# Using LESS css in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, less

Is there a way to implement a LESS stylesheet in a codeigniter project without having to rely on sparks and Carabiner?

In the  of my view in CI, I place the link to the LESS file, and the LESS.js file directly underneath, however when I view the site, CI doesn't recognize the .LESS file. I've tried using relative paths as well as hardcoding the the file directories directly, however nothing changes. Is there something I should try adding to my config file to load the LESS files properly?

My file structure for the CI project is as follows

- application

  - controllers
  - views
- system
- js

  - less-1.2.2.min.js
  - plugins.js
- css

  - style.css
  - style.less

As for my header, its based off of the html5 boilerplate, to save space I'll only include the relevant info.

application -> views -> layout.php

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.less">
<script src="js/less-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
<!-- end CSS-->
```

Comment: You say your file is `less.1.2.2.min.js`, but you're including `less-1.2.2.min.js` -- is that mis-match just a typo in your question?

Comment: yes, sorry about that. It should be less-1.2.2.min.js, not less.1.2.2.min.js

Comment: Is Carabiner even still actively developed? I used it once and it was *bloated*, haven't looked back since. You definitely don't *need* it for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using mod_rewrite in httpd.conf? If so, you need to make sure that .less files are exempted.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^alocalfarmCI/index\.php|\.png$|\.gif$|\.less$|\.js$|\.css$|/robots
```

One way to easily tell if this is your problem, type in a non-existent url within your site that ends in .less. If you see CI's error page, that means /index.php/ was inserted in the url.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running with client-side (javascript) LESS, Codeigniter won't be involved in how LESS operates. Be sure that you've set the `rel` attribute appropriately when you're linking your LESS file in your views and that the less.js file is being loaded correctly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Everything is linked correctly. I have my javascript and less files in the project root directory. Developer Tools shows both the js and LESS file have the correct paths, and the js file loads and I can view in in DT, however the LESS file cannot be found and clicking the link on the source directs me back to the js file.

Comment: Hmm, that's probably where your issue is happening, then. Could you update your question with the relevant directory structure and the code you're using in your view?